# Is there any bug in the code given below?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am getting an issue to run the below code.The code gives no error but not giving the expected output. Any suggestions or solution will be highly appreciated.Thanx in advance.

Here's my xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/readWebpage"
            android:text="Load Webpage"
            android:onClick="readWebpage"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:text="Example Text"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's my java file:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoadWebpageAsyncTask extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }
    public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String response = "";
            for(String url:urls){
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try{
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
                            InputStreamReader(execute.getEntity().getContent()));
                    String s="";
                    while((s = br.readLine()) != null){

                        response += s;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            tv.setText(result);
        }

    }

        public void readWebpage(View view){ 
            DownloadWebpageTask task = new DownloadWebpageTask();
            task.execute(new String[]{"http://www.google.com"});

            }
}
```

Comment: What is the unexpected output?

Comment: Problem solved thanxs for the comments....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing `setContentView(R.layout.<...>);` (`tv` will be null) in your `onCreate()` method and never run your task (so you don't get `NullPointerException` when setting text on `tv`):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    readWebpage(null); //you never use argument anyway
}
```

**edit** riha's answer is also true, since the way you use it is `for (String[] url:urls)`, not `for (String url:urls)`

Comment: Haha yeah, now that you mention it, setContentView() is missing. Might the argument to readWebpage be mandatory since he assigned it as onClick in XML?

Comment: @riha ouch, you are right. i didn't took a close look at xml file >_<

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to provide a String array to execute(). That should be sufficient:

```
task.execute("http://www.google.com");
```

You could provide several URLs like so:

```
task.execute("url1", "url2");
```

If things still don't work, do some debugging: Take the code of your AsyncTask and place it in onCreate(). Put a breakpoint on it and walk through it carefully to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: +1, i missed that part when writing my answer